# Graph pre-order/post-order traversal?

Tags: java, data-structures, traversal, depth-first-search

This is a DFS pre-order vertex numbering which corresponds to a pre-order traversal of the DFS tree and the second one is A post-order numbering which corresponds to a post-order traversal of the DFS tree.

Can someone please explain how did we get this ordering because I only know how to apply pre-order or post-order only on binary trees. thank you

[image: pre-order numbering]

[image: post-order numbering]

Comment: do you know how DFS work? if Preorder 1.select root node with minimum weight i.e 1 in your eg.. and then 2.search and select another  node whose weight is less then all other node except parent and its should not form cycle and repeat step 2 till you cover all vertex

Comment: The DFS works similarly over any graph as with a (binary) tree - the primary difference is that the algorithm has to explicitly prevent cycles in cyclic graphs (which don't occur in trees). This can be implicitly taken care of if the node values follow some defined rules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to follow this pseudocode step by step with your example and you will understand the algorithm, it's very easy and just plain DFS:

```
Initialize clock to 1

PreVisit(v):
    pre[v] <- clock
    clock <- clock + 1

PostVisit(v):
    post[v] <- clock
    clock <- clock + 1

Explore(v):
    visited[v] = true
    PreVisit(v)
    for all u adj to v:
        if u is not visited:
            Explore(u)
    PostVisit(v)
```

Note that you have to create an array of `pre`, `post`, and `visited` with the length of vertices. For the `visited` array, you have to fill it with `false` before you call `Explore(v)`.

Comment: You should also define different clocks for pre- and postvisit numbers